# Convert all xml files of a directory to CSV in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


def xml_to_csv(path):
    xml_list = []
    for xml_file in glob.glob(path + '/*.xml'):
        tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
        root = tree.getroot()
        for member in root.findall('object'):
            value = (root.find('filename').text,
                     int(root.find('size')[0].text),
                     int(root.find('size')[1].text),
                     member[0].text,
                     int(member[4][0].text),
                     int(member[4][1].text),
                     int(member[4][2].text),
                     int(member[4][3].text)
                     )
            xml_list.append(value)
    column_name = ['filename', 'width', 'height', 'class', 'xmin', 'ymin', 'xmax', 'ymax']
    xml_df = pd.DataFrame(xml_list, columns=column_name)
    return xml_df


def main():
    for directory in ['train','test']:
        image_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'images/{}'.format(directory))
        xml_df = xml_to_csv(image_path)
        xml_df.to_csv('Data/{}_labels.csv'.format(directory), index=None)
        print('Successfully converted xml to csv.')


main()
```

So, I took this code from somewhere. It is supposed to convert CSV file from xml files.

I do have the directory 'train' and 'test' in the same place where this python file is located. And have a bunch of xml files in both directories.

When I run this it does create two csv files inside 'Data' directory. But when I open these csv files, I see them empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML parsing loop returned no relevant results.

You say the *.xml glob matches a "bunch" of files. Ok, let's assume that is so. Add a debugging `print(value)` statement just before the `.append()`.

If it turns out that it never executes, then you will want to debug why the tree root lacks an `'object'` node.